# The argument type 'Item' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, contacts

I am trying to iterate over a phone list to display mobile numbers for the contact using package `contacts_service`.

The class `UserContactItem` holds the info of the contact and when I pass it`s elements to `userContact` it gives me this error:

```
Compiler message:
lib/home.dart:117:28: Error: The argument type 'Item' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'.
 - 'Item' is from 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart' ('../../../../../../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/contacts_service-0.3.10/lib/contacts_service.dart').
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
          number: mobilenum[0],
                           ^
```

here is class UserContactItem:

```dart
class UserContactItem{


final String contactName;
  final List number;

  UserContactItem({this.contactName, this.number});
}
```

here is the iteration over phone elements:

```
final Iterable<Contact> contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();

var iter = 0;
contacts.forEach((contact) async{
  var mobilenum = contact.phones.toList();

  if(mobilenum.length != 0){
    var userContact = UserContactItem(
      contactName: contact.displayName,
      number: mobilenum[0],
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: How does Item look like? Please share the class Item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, in the class UserContactItem, you have defined that the number will be of type **List<*dynamic*>**.

```
class UserContactItem{
final String contactName;
  final List number; //here
  UserContactItem({this.contactName, this.number});
}
```

And later, you are assigning ***mobilenum[0]*** to it which is of type ***Item***. Which can't be assigned.

You should change the type of **number** in UserContactItem to **Item**.

```
class UserContactItem{
final String contactName;
  final Item number; //like this
  UserContactItem({this.contactName, this.number});
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks a lot.. It was my first time to use Item variable